# Deserializing Data into Appropriate Handler Object

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

For a system of any complexity, there are most likely going to be many objects serializing data.

For example, say each serialized object derives from `IData`. And we have multiple `ISerializer` objects, that serialize their data into via Json.net, what are best practices for deserializing that data and determining the appropriate `ISerializer` object to handle the data?

When I deserizlie some `IData`I don't know which of my `ISerializer` objects to invoke `HandleData` on.

Comment: Why is it a given that we will have multiple `ISerializer` objects? Give me an example scenario where multiple `ISerializer` objects would exist.

Comment: Say you have a collection of independent objects. Each one with very specialized knowledge that has nothing to do with the other. Instead of having a central point of serialization that has to know about each of these object's, I have an interface ISerializer that the objects implement *if* they want to serliaize some data. My serialization routine then becomes enumeration across the collection, see which obj's implement the interface, and calling serialize() on them returning back a base type that I write out to json.